# User-defined literal doesn't work when the body is written in a different .cpp file

Tags: c++, literals, user-defined-literals

I created a user-defined literal like this, in is OWN `.cpp` file (declared as a `friend` function in `.h` file):

```
fraction operator"" _frac(const long double val)
{
    return fraction(static_cast<float>(val));
}
```

But in `main` it produces this error:

```
Error (active)E2486 user-defined literal operator not found
```

But, when I write the SAME code (definitely the same, as I copy it, and also do some words comparison) in `main` or `.h`(outside of the class scope) file, it works fine, why?

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and C++20 ([GitHub Files](https://github.com/KhiemGOM/fraction)).

`Test.h`:

```
#pragma once
class test
{
    double x;
public:
    explicit test(const double a) : x(a) {};
    friend test operator "" _t(long double a);
};
```

`Test.cpp`:

```
#include "Test.h"

test operator "" _t(const long double a)
{
    return test(a);
}
```

`main`:

```
#include "Test.h"

int main()
{
    test t = 12_t; //error
}
```

Yes, I know that this is due to the fact that it doesn't have a parameter which is a class, which makes it internal to the class. I want to ask how to declare this in the `.cpp` file but still be acessible from `main` (declaration and friend keywords in `.h` doesn't matter).

### What I have tried:

- I created other classes, and use an older version of C++, I still get the same result (definition in the same file as `main` works fine, but if written in another file it doesn't work). I can accept to write it in the same file, but then what's the purpose of orientated programming anymore?
- Using the `extern` keyword can help, but my compiler doesn't like it, and it's also very inconvenient every time I have to write that in `main`.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. Have you forward-declared the user-defined literal in any header file? Have you forgotten to `#include` the header file containing the declaration? Please [edit] your post to include a complete example of 50 lines or less that causes the same error.

Comment: In the spirit of this forum, do you have a question to ask? Please see [ask].

Comment: @JaMiT No because in there they don't suggest a solution?

Comment: @JustAnOnion They do suggest a solution – you need a global declaration since a friend declaration does not make the name available to "not argument-dependent" lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user-defined literal function just is not declared in your `main.cpp`.

Place

```
test operator "" _t(const long double a);
```

in your `test.h`

Comment: Do you mean place that outside or inside class scope? (Both of them don't work anyway?)

Comment: @JustAnOnion, Outside. What error do you get when try this?

Comment: Oh it worked, I write 12 not 12.0, my mistake